# JSplitPane divider color affected by contents

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, divider, jsplitpane

I'm working on an application that displays two JScrollPanes within a JSplitPane. Each of the JScrollPanes contains a JPanel that I'm drawing the content onto. The problem is that when I adjust the divider of the JScrollPane, the color of the divider is affected. It seems to take on the appearance of the JPanel inside of it - that is, the background of the divider has snippets of the words and colors I'm displaying in the JPanel.

It seems like I'm missing a revalidate() or something here, but I can't get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me you you might be forgetting:

```
super.paintComponent(g)
```

in the custom painting of the panel.

If you need more help then you need to post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.